# Core Data crash on a seemingly normal NSString field

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have another strange bug which I cannot figure out.

I try to create a tableviewcell with the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableViewCellController *cell = (TableViewCellController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [_cell autorelease];
        _cell = nil;
    } 

    // Configure the cell... 

 int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
 Article *article = (Article *)[articles objectAtIndex: storyIndex];
 cell.titleLabel.text = article.title;
 cell.siteLabel.text = article.site.name;

 cell.summaryLabel.text = article.description;

 [article release];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that I can populate the labels with any value, except with the description value. As soon as I do that I get a the following crash:

> 2010-12-22 16:07:13.165 iDoms[24086:207] CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x8b16dd0 
>   Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
>   warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
>   Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)

with 62820 line items on the stack.
I have no idea where to start figuring this out. I am used to Java, and Objective-C has been a real nightmare so-far regarding little strange bugs.

The Article class looks like this:

```
//  Article.h

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Site;

@interface Article :  NSManagedObject  
{

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * read;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * link;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * pubDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastUpdate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Site * site;


@end
```

and

```
//  Article.m

#import "Article.h"

@implementation Article 

@dynamic id;
@dynamic title;
@dynamic read;
@dynamic link;
@dynamic pubDate;
@dynamic description;
@dynamic lastUpdate;
@dynamic site;

@end
```

The database contains data, and the particular field just the string "Test1".
Any help is really appreciated as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this is related to your current issue, but you do not want to do the [article release]; in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, as objectAtIndex does not give you a reference that needs to be released.

Comment: Thanks, I tied a bit up on my release statements, and hopefully that will make the whole code a bit more stable. I am new to Objective-C, coming from Java where I never really ran into release issues before.

Comment: It can be tricky to learn memory management in Objective-C, it took me a long time to get it down to the point of it becoming second nature.  At first, I just learned to just start commenting out calls to release to get the code working, and then later went back and tried to chase down the leaks by releasing when necessary.

Comment: If you haven't seen the Apple developer docs on memory management, they are worth a quick look:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 3):

The size of the stack trace leads me to believe that you've got an infinite recursion loop going somewhere.

I would look at the construction of the custom UITableViewCell that is getting created, namely the summaryLabel control and how it is wired into the cell.

I would also make sure that the articles array is property retained.

Comment: I think the problem was that 'description' is also a property of NSString, I changed that, and it seems to work now. There still seems to be some problems with some memory allocations, but I will try and work my way through that. I will check the retainment of "articles".

Comment: BP has an excellent insight.  The [article release] could be setting the retain count to 0 on that managed entity, which may inturn cause it to be released, reducing the retain count on each property which could cause them to be released in error, which could trigger all manner of weird (non-Java like) behaviors.